# Excel - Aggregate: Extract data from non blank cells

Tags: excel, if-statement, extract, aggregate-functions

I have a large sum of data in excel with many rows and columns, a lot are blank, from where I want to extract data based on 1 criteria with 4 options to choose from. Options include: Amsterdam, Paris, Madrid and All. So when I select Amsterdam all the data for Amsterdam should be extracted, same goes for Paris & Madrid. For the option of "All" I want to extract all the data for all the locations (Amsterdam, Paris and Madrid).

I'm using this formula:

```
=IF(ROWS(B$5:B5)>$J$3,"",INDEX(source[DATE],AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(source[DATE])-ROW(source[#Headers]))/SIGN((($E$3="All")+(source[OFFICE]=$E$3))),ROWS(B$5:B5))))
```

With this formula I'm perfectly able to extract dates for the locations: Amsterdam, Paris and Madrid but whenever I select "All" the formula just extracts the first row from the raw data (most are blank). I know what I'm doing wrong but I don't know how to fix it.

Link to an example:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/37p4jdxqul2enf4/data%20extract%20non%20blank.xlsx?dl=0

Sheet: Extract E3 is a dropdown list from where I choose the Location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a condition for the row containing the information not to be blank:

```
=IF(ROWS(B$5:B5)>$J$3,"",INDEX(source[DATE],AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(source[DATE])-ROW(source[#Headers]))/SIGN((($E$3="All")+(source[OFFICE]=$E$3))*(source[OFFICE]<>"")),ROWS(B$5:B5))))
```

You might have to change what you have in J3, or add an IFERROR to the formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(ROWS(B$5:B5)>$J$3,"",INDEX(source[DATE],AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(source[DATE])-ROW(source[#Headers]))/SIGN((($E$3="All")+(source[OFFICE]=$E$3))*(source[OFFICE]<>"")),ROWS(B$5:B5)))),"")
```

Comment: Great! It works perfectly, thank you! Also thanks for your suggestion.